# How do I make my base domain go directly to my index.php file on an ubuntu 16.04 VPS with LAMP?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, indexing, dns

I'm running a linux ubuntu 16.04 VPS with a LAMP stack

I have a virtual host set up to display my website (let's call it website.com), there is an SSL cert that works and redirects http requests to https

My website is in php, hence the index page is index.php

**Here's the issue: the base domain (website.com) is not pointing to the index.php file**

In the browser I can type **www.website.com** and it will point directly to my index.php and will also redirect the request to https.

When I type **website.com/index.php** my website will be displayed and properly redirected to https.

The more specific problem comes in when I type **website.com** into the browser (without adding /index.php), the only thing displayed is the default apache server webpage.

I have 2 DNS record types set for this domain:

1. A record - points to my VPS IP address
2. A record for the sub-domain (www) - points to my VPS IP address

I have modified the directory index in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` so it looks like this:

`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm`

Any help is appreciated, thanks everyone
PS - This is my first stackoverflow question!!!!!!

Comment: Can you be able to show us virtual host file and .htaccess file? Did you check mod rewrite engine on or off?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you restart apache after doing so?

Comment: How do you redirect to https?  Perhaps you can dump/share your apache config/vhosts - redact personal information.

Comment: I appreciate your quick responses, I had an idea in the middle of the night and tried it first thing when I turned my PC on, it ended up fixing my problem. It's super embarrassing but I'll tell you the solution.

**I removed the index.html fie from my public_html folder**

yeah, sorry for wasting your time :(...

Comment: Although it serves its purpose, it is not a good practise to have index file out of public folder, as all the files on the same level (including business logic) will be accessible from browser. I myself am looking for the solution but to no avail so far.